# How can I obtain hourly readings from 24 hour moving average data?

Tags: excel, moving-average

I have an excel dataset of 24-hour moving averages for PM10 air pollution concentration levels, and need to obtain the individual hourly readings from them. The moving average data is updated every hour, so at hour t, the reading is the average of the 24 readings from t-23 to t hours, and at hour t+1, the reading is the average of t-22 to t+1, etc. I do not have any known data points to extrapolate from, just the 24-hour moving averages.

Is there any way I can obtain the individual hourly readings for time t, t+1, etc, from the moving average?

The dataset contains data over 3 years, so with 24 readings a day (at every hour), the dataset has thousands of readings.

I have tried searching for a possible way to implement a simple excel VBA code to do this, but come up empty. Most of the posts I have seen on Stackoverflow and stackexchange, or other forums, involve calculating moving averages from discrete data, which is the reverse of what I need to do here.

The few I have seen involve using matrices, which I am not very sure how to implement. ([Extract data points from moving average?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67907/extract-data-points-from-moving-average)) ([Estimating original series from their moving average](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112502/estimating-original-series-from-their-moving-average))

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As stated in the other threads you linked to: It is crucial how the moving averages dealt with the ends. Please edit your answer and address this issue.

Comment: Excel supports some basic matrix operations, including inversion, making it straightforward to implement the matrix solution.